# What to do with the two tags for Experts-Exchange?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently two tags for questions about SE's old competitor [Experts-Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange):

---

[experts-exchange](/questions/tagged/experts-exchange)

[Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experts-exchange): 10

Usage Guidance:

> Experts-Exchange.com (EE) is a membership-based online "ask an expert" site for computing related questions.

---

[hyphenated-site](/questions/tagged/hyphenated-site)

[Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphenated-site): 4

Usage Guidance:

> Experts-Exchange is a Q&A site similar to Stack Overflow, catering to software developers.

---

Both were almost created at the same time ([experts-exchange](/questions/tagged/experts-exchange) 9 years 6 months ago, [hyphenated-site](/questions/tagged/hyphenated-site) 9 years 5 months ago).
Both also have wikis with the one for [experts-exchange](/questions/tagged/experts-exchange) being shorter and more neutral.

**Are both tags needed or only one (and which one)?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done. The tags have been merged:

`hyphenated-site` → [experts-exchange](/questions/tagged/experts-exchange)

Answer (score 10):

The term "hyphenated-site" isn't well known at all, especially these days. Only few will understand questions with this tag are actually about Experts Exchange site.

So this tag should go away in my opinion. Best and most simple is to just retag those four questions to be [experts-exchange](/questions/tagged/experts-exchange) instead.

Comment: Absolutely. "hyphenated-site" is a very silly tag name.

Comment: The name comes from the fact that the site previously lacked the hyphen in the domain, and people were mentally inserting spaces in the wrong spots.

Comment: @Sonic thanks, that's useful trivia. :-)